# Edit Function for SAP Fiori Template with ODATA

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide

In the Web IDE it is very easy to create a Fiori App from a Master Detail Template and adding an ODATA service.
But this new created app only displays the data from the ODATA service.
What is the correct way to add a Create or Edit function after adding the new view and a save button?
How should the onSavePressed function look like?
Do I have to create an ODataModel in this function or is it already present anywhere in the template?
Is the structure of this template already correct and complete or do I have to change it?
I only read about createEntry() and submitChanges() in the documentations but not how to use/implement them.
Are there any simple instructions or demo apps?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

In the WebIDE you can also: File -> New -> Project from Sample Application
Do you find an app called “Manage Products”?
When you run it, do you find an “Edit”-button in the bottom right corner?
Is this, what you are looking for?